# Connection to Asus router

Tags: wifi, router

Connection to internet is allowed for only one specified device (always the same one laptop). I made the factory reset, after that the problem still exists. The other devices (Android, Symbian, another laptop) can connect to Wifi, but cannot connect to internet. Two weeks ago there wasn't any problem with the devices mentioned above.

Thanks a lot:
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be a question related to programming/development. I think [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) would be a better place for this question.

Comment: Or maybe http://superuser.com/ .  This probably should have been a comment, rather than an answer, but since you don't have the rep for that, here's an upvote to help you on your way.

Comment: I agree, but my account is new and it would not allow me to add as a comment, at that time. Thanks for the up vote.